# How to create VStack within HStack with equal element widths?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is my code to create `HStack` with equal width elements for full width parent `View`:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
        Color(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1))
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .padding(2)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
.frame(height: 70)
```

and the effect is:

[image]

But now I need to add the center `"T"` text inside every `View` at the top, so I simply replace `Color` view with `VStack` view and:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("T")
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .padding(2)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
.frame(height: 70)
```

and the effect is wrong. Why?

[image]

What to do to keep size of the rectangle views with `"T"`, as it was without `"T"`?

Comment: Did you try to first define frame size, and then background? sometimes order of modifiers matters, and I think this is that time. Ie. `VStack{...}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color...)`

Comment: Seriously? Ok, let me try first...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `scaledToFill()` on both the `VStack` and the `HStack`:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("T")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .padding(2)
        .scaledToFill()
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 70)
.scaledToFill()
```

[image]

And where the `.frame()` is set does make a difference as pointed out by @timbre

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest watching WWDC 2019 [Building Custom Views with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237), as this video (esp the first half) outlines the basic layout process, illustrating how text fields request only the space they need.

But in this case, as timbretimbre said, order matters. Just set the `frame` of the `VStack` view first:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("T")
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.1))       // we don’t need UIColor
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding(2)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 70) 
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to use an overlay for what your are trying to achieve:

```
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
                Color.red.opacity(0.1)
                    .overlay {
                        Text("T")
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .padding(2)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 70)
```

Yout don't need `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier since `Color` by default already takes up all the space available. If you don't want any color in the background set it to `.clear`.

Comment: This is what I understood in "What to do to keep size of the rectangle views with "T", as it was without "T"?".
Additionally you can put the text in a VStack or/and do whatever you want in the overlay it will work just fine ;)

Comment: Sorry I was misled by the red color (he wanted the “T” in lieu of the red color, not on top of it). I now get what you were saying…